# Use MuClipse to get mutant and test case information

Tags: java, testing, eclipse-plugin, mutation-testing

I'm using MuClipse and I need to get information about which use case kills which mutant. MuClipse provides only the mutation score. How do I get that information from MuClipse?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to compute a kill matrix (*mutants m_1...m_n* vs. *test cases t_1...t_m*). Note that the kill-matrix computation is not a standard feature in most mutation tools because it is not required to compute the mutation score: once a mutant is killed by a test case, there is no need to execute other test cases on the same mutant [[1](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~rjust/publ/mutation_test_prio_issre_2012.pdf)].

As far as I know, MuClipse does not support the computation of a kill matrix and is not longer maintained. You could write a wrapper that 1) executes each test case in isolation and 2) merges all individual test case executions to form the kill matrix. Alternatively, you might want to take a look at [Major](http://mutation-testing.org/), which supports the kill-matrix computation out of the box.

Comment: thank you, your answer really help me. i am trying to use major tool but i have problem in the instillation, i have  the latest version of jdk and i follow the  instillation part in major document (install the file and extract them then add its bin folder to path variable ) but when i test it by write the command "javac -version" only my jdk version appear so i can not go after !.. is there something wrong i have made